# Ruby on Rails, Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Api::UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting this error in the console, something like the page code:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0px;
    }
......
```

Errors occur when registering or logging in, on the local server everything goes well, and on heroku this is the error, so I think that the problem in setting up production.rb is this:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in     config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
}
else
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

config.cache_store = :null_store
end

# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
config.assets.compile = false

# Raises error for missing translations
# config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

# Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
# routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
# config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => '****'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                  587,
domain:               'gmail.com',
user_name:            '****',
password:             '****',
authentication:       :plain,
# enable_starttls_auto: true
}
end
```

Even when I comment on the message sending code, the error does not crash and registration passes without error, but no message is sent, which I think is logical.

Here is another mistake that we managed to catch:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Api::UsersController#create
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsn


21    if @user.save
22      origin = request.headers['origin']
23      ApplicationMailer.registration_confirmation(@user, origin).deliver
24      render :show, status: :ok
25    else
26      render json: {
```

Comment: Try replacing `authentication:` value `:plain` by `:login`,
or/and uncomment `enable_starttls_auto: true` since you are on port 587 (https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

Comment: I tried every combinations of your advice, but they didn't help me and I still don't find decision of my problem.

Comment: So, since it raise SMTPAuthenticationError, maybe your login information are invalid or your google account config (for example 2 factor auth enabled)... Could you try with another SMTP (mailtrap.io, sendgrid, etc) ?

Comment: Yes, this is my mistake, I included the main mail, and I allowed access, but I had to allow it to a completely different account. Thanks.